# HTML with CSS formating in QTextEdit (Qt)

Tags: python, html, css, qt, pyqt

I am having troubles with formating a HTML text in a QTextEdit. I have an inline style within the HTML text, but only some of the CSS features I am triying to use are working. For example, I cannot set a justify alignment, but I can center the text. Is there a way to put into the QTextEdit *pure* HTML text so the Qt Style Sheet of the QTextEdit does not affect the text, and I can modify it freely with all the CSS features?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: Note: Anything is possible including this what it entails to implement though might be more than necessary. Can I ask why you are attempting to do this with a QTextEdit container?

Comment: I don't know how else I can do it.

Comment: How about [Qt WebEngine](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-overview.html)?